# Suggest a text editor or IDE for chapel programming language

Tags: editor, chapel

I want to write some short numerical programs in chapel. Can somebody just tell an IDE, or text editor which supports code highlighting for chapel (chapel-aware), is there an elisp-file for `emacs`? I don't prefer `vim`, even if a script for `vim` exists.

I tried searching, but I couldn't find anything. I neither know `emacs-lisp` nor am completely aware of chapel's syntax to configure it to make this chapel-aware.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the elisp files and .vimrc files ship along with chapel tar.gz file , so after extracting the tar.gz file in a folder chapel-*version*/highlight/vim or chapel-*version*/highlight/emacs there the vimrc or elisp files are present and in the README , instructions are also given how to add to init files ~/.emacs or ~/.vim.

Comment: Adding on to fedvasu's answer: Note that as of Chapel 1.13, the etc directory has been renamed to highlight; so the current paths are `$CHPL_HOME/highlight/emacs` or `$CHPL_HOME/highlight/vim`.

Comment: If you're not working out of the release tarball, you can find the the files in the git repository: [vim plugin](https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/tree/master/highlight/vim),  [emacs mode](https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/tree/master/highlight/emacs)

Answer (score 4):

I have just come across a plugin for the [Atom Editor](https://atom.io/) that does [Chapel Highlighting](https://github.com/fsouza/language-chapel)

Comment: ( Btw, a sad point is, that this has been advised exactly a year ago, but "hyper-activistic" community-censors have deleted this answer and left everyone interested in the [Chapel] to have to re-search the already solved answer. For details >>>https://stackoverflow.com/a/39195945 )

Answer (score 3):

There is an Emacs mode for Chapel at MELPA. So if you are using an Emacs with package management you can just install chapel-mode.

https://melpa.org/#/chapel-mode